Deleting all json files from all subfolders of a specific folder after publish
In my .net Blazor Server project, I have the following structure:
\App_Data\Config\
\App_Data\SystemRepository\
\App_Data\UserRepository\

UserRepository folder contains many folders and json files. Each of those folders have multiple json files.
I do not want those json files in UserRepository in the publish folder. However, I want to keep the subfolder structure in tact.
I am using publish UI from visual studio to publish the app in a folder. I have tried adding this to csproj
<Target Name="RemoveJsonFilesAfterPublish" AfterTargets="Publish">
    <ItemGroup>
        <JsonFilesToDelete Include="$(PublishDir)App_Data\UserRepository\**\*.json" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Delete Files="@(JsonFilesToDelete)" />
</Target>

But this deletes the entire UserRepository folder.
How to achieve this through csproj? I will resort to post build scripts only if this doesn't work.

I'm not sure but shouldn't it be possible to exclude the JSON files from publishing?

It is, but I want to exclude json files from specific folders only. Also, these json files are not named. They are dynamically generated.
